# Will \usepackage[UTF8]{ctex} change the appearance of my non-Chinese part LaTeX document?

Tags: ctex

I'm very new with LaTeX. I'm using it to write a document and 70% of the content is English and left is Chinese.

After some research I found just by adding `\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}` in the document, I can use Chinese in the document correctly. Will `\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}` change the appearance of the non-Chinese part of the document?

I can't see any big differences, but I just want to confirm.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will change the scheme, for example, the section name will be centered instead of ragged right.

However, you may use the `scheme=plain` to support Chinese only, without changing the appearance.

The default is `scheme=chinese`, and the following things will be changed:

- Default font size becomes "five" (五号, wuhao), and line spread becomes 1.3
- Caption names (e.g. `Figure`) will be translated into Chinese
- Paragraph after chapter/section titles will have indent as well (using `indentfirst` package)

You may find more details in [ctex's document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/chinese/ctex/ctex.pdf) (unfortunately only Chinese version is available).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll take a look at the ctex doc.