# What are the problems for CTeX in pdfLaTeX?

Tags: ctex

While I do not produce documents in Chinese, I quote enough Chinese to be very happy that CTeX exists. I have used CJKutf8.  Now simple examples in CTeX work fine for me using pdfLaTeX.  The CTeX documentation (p. 6) says that to use pdfLaTeX I must make sure to used GBK encoding.  No problem.

Experimenting shows me that it is feasible to use CTeX for small parts of a largely English document. I am aware of

[Will \usepackage[UTF8]{ctex} change the appearance of my non-Chinese part LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450961/will-usepackageutf8ctex-change-the-appearance-of-my-non-chinese-part-latex?rq=1)

But I do not know what all the problems might be, especially using pdfLaTeX.

More specifically, CTeX documentation Table 3 in section 4.3 seems to say that when using pdfLaTeX, CTeX macros cannot automatically configure font strategies. That section notes some other problems for pdfLaTeX and font configuration. My TeX is too poor for me to know what font configuration means.  So I wonder if this will cause me trouble.

Later section 11.5 (translated) says

> Usually users only need to refer to the method described in Section
>   2.2 to install this macro set using the package manager that comes with the distribution.

Probably I am one of the usual users who can just use the package manager as in the method of section 2.2.

The rest of the documentation seems to discuss pdfLaTeX only for fairly sophisticated issues that I never know about anyway, with any package I use.

But can anyone tell me in short what problems a user like myself, who never writes macros anyway, might have using CTeX in pdfLaTeX?